# Using method on a switch argument in switch case block java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to explore substrings using switch case block. for now I am trying to do this:

```
    switch(splitedString[0]){

    case(.contains("int")):
    }
```

When I need to create new object when the case is met. There is any option to activate method on the switch argument?

Comment: No, there isn't. Use `if`.

Comment: Something to note is that in a `switch` statement you shouldn't be able to hit two different cases (or the same case twice). Using methods easily breaks that contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do such thing. Also putting string in a switch statement is more like if statement.

Instead of using switch use if's

**sample:**

```
if(splitedString[0].contains("int"))
```